# What makes Kuka robots better?

Tags: kuka

KUKA seems to be everywhere, why are they better?
Or, what makes one robot(robotic arm) better than
another anyway?

How much does the raw material of a robot cost
compared to its price? Is most of the cost
of the robot in Intellectual property?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user26787, but I'm afraid that questions which ask about the Pros/cons or Advantages/disadvantages are effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 2):

Kuka is not generally better. Better at some aspects, worst at others. Kuka does not seem to have the largest market share by revenue (according to [this](https://www.statista.com/statistics/257177/global-industrial-robot-market-share-by-company/)article from 2017) (Admittedly direct revenue from industrial robot sales is hard to measure and the article is old)

If a robot arm is better or worst then the other one is heavily application and context dependent. A different manufacturer might fit the application better, but if a company already has a number of Kuka robots, they will probably keep buying Kuka robots, as mixing different brand will increase maintenance and training costs.

Kuka robots offer some advanced software packages that go beyond just moving the robot. Software packages e.g for welding integrate with welding tools and ease the workload of robotic welding engineers by offering an integrated solution. Kuka is not the only manufacturer doing this, but it is recognized as one of the robot manufacturers, who offers more advanced software features, a large number of integrations with other equipment and advanced SW features which go beyond simple robot motion.

Generally the positioning precision, maximum velocity, reach and maximum payload is comparable between the top industrial robot manufacturers, with small exceptions, like Kuka and Fanuc offering extra high payload capacity. There are some differences in the mechanical capabilities, but the main difference between robots is software features and functions and technical support from the manufacturer.

It is hard to say what is the raw material cost of a robot, since robot manufacturers have (presumably) significant discounts on list prices from suppliers (raw metal suppliers,  motor suppliers, gearbox suppliers, drive amplifier suppliers, connector suppliers, cable suppliers, cabinet suppliers, to name only the big ticket items). Building a prototype robot (incl. mech and elec design) without software, at list prices would be probably more expensive then buying a robot. One could speculate, that the  materials and equipment used in an industrial robot should be less then half of the cost of the robot, for a robot manufacturer, since the robot sales should be able to keep the company profitable. (And there are many auxiliary activities which need to be carried out at these companies, besides the actual production)

IP can be a big issue and robot manufacturer patent their designs and inventions at a significant cost, but patents for the **most basic** functions of a robot have expired a long time ago.